# What does getch() really get? Scan codes?

Tags: c, console-application, mingw32, getch, conio

```
#include <conio.h>

int main (void)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        unsigned char ch = getch();
        printf ("0x%02X\n", ch);
    }
}
```

I want to get the scan code.

Here is the description from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h):

```
    Reads a character directly from the console without buffer, and without echo.
```

When I pressed <kbd>Del</kbd>, it shows 0xE0 0x53.

When I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>, it shows 0xE0 0x86.

Though some are the same as the table, most of the values it shows are different from it.

So, does `getch()` really get scan codes?

Here is the scan code table (set 2, most commonly used)

[image: Scan Code]

Comment: is that really the code you are using? it should print a zero padded decimal number of 3 digits followed by the hex. i'm curious that there isn't a bug somewhere since 0x86 seems only unproducible. what happens for the num pad pg up?

Comment: @user3125280 Sorry. I edited the code.

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia and that gives you these exact results? the only way i can see 0x86 produced is from set 1, when the 5 key is release (0x80 + 0x06) and this would not be preceded by e0.

Comment: @user3125280 They should be preceded by 0xE0. Visit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode#PC_compatibles).

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia the particular example i gave (from set 1, not your case) would not include 0xe0 - pg up and del both do. What about num pad pg up? what does that give you?

Comment: @user3125280 Sorry, I am using laptop. :-(

Comment: What compiler are you using? MSDN web page about [_getch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) implies it's returning ANSI or UNICODE, not scan codes. Take a look at the example that looks for 'y' or 'Y' .

Answer (score 0):

I ran a console app in VS 2012 (C++) and got the same results as you.  It did say that getch() was deprecated and I should use _getch(), but that made no difference.

I then found a table here that matches it (right-most column).  For me, the "white" keys were using shift and the numeric keypad equivalents, the "grey" keys were the stand-alone page-up, page-down, etc.  The one discrepancy I found was enter on the numeric keypad is the same as the regular enter key.

http://www.itlnet.net/programming/program/Reference/msc/ng7d68f.html

I don't know where this table comes from, other than if you click on "About The Guide" it says "The Microsoft C Database,  Copyright (C) 1987,  by Peter Norton".  Where Peter got it, I don't know.

Comment: Andries Brouwer has a detailed discussion of different keyboard scancodes at his site: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but that table seems similar to other standard tables I've found, and in all of them there is no 0x86

Comment: crud, you're right.  I was looking for the 86, but Google hits kept coming up with other things (x86), so then I focused on page-down codes instead of page-up codes, and forgot to check both at the end.

Comment: Well from the look of the table gray and white ctrl pageup are equal - maybe the laptop just uses a different scan code, to differentiate (even though it only has one pageup). Maybe if OP posted more scan codes..